# Database.GetDbConnection error after the migration from .NET Core 2.1 into .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I  just migrated my application from **.NET Core 2.1** into  **.NET Core 3.1** , But after that, I am getting the error in the place wherever I have used **dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection**.

Here I was using the namespace System.Data.SqlClient. So How can I change the code to work with **.NET Core 3.1** I have given the code below.

When I try to change **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient**,  the error cannot convert from **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection** to '**string**' would be shown, Please give a help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

public UserRepository(dbContext db) : base(db)
    {
        _db= db;
    }
var conn = (SqlConnection)_db.Database.GetDbConnection();
                DataTable dtMissingDates = new DataTable();
            SqlParameter parUserId = new SqlParameter("@UserId", userId);
            SqlParameter parDepots = new SqlParameter("@DepotNo", depono);
                SqlParameter parDepartment = new SqlParameter("@DepartmentID", department);
                SqlParameter parDate = new SqlParameter("@DateTo",attdate);
            SqlHelper.FillDatatable(conn
                                            , CommandType.StoredProcedure
                                            , StoredProcedureConstants.GET_DEPOT_MISSING_ATT_POPUP
                                            , dtMissingDates
                                            , MTSGOConstants.DEFAULT_COMMAND_TIME_OUT
                                            , parUserId
                                            , parDepots
                                            , parDepartment
                                            ,parDate);
```

Thanks
Pol

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get **connection string** and **connection**, you could use this commands to get related object or string :

```
var connectionString = _db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
var connection = _db.Database.Connection as SqlConnection;
```

Answer (score 0):

`nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`

install this package

helpful source : https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7810